# UWP App Crash Issue After Deploy

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UWP App that implements Cortana functionality to navigate pages. I'm deploying it in VS2015 Community on the Debug/x64 configuration.

I can say "open {my app}" and it works fine, then "open {my app} to {book} and {chapter}" and it works fine if the app is already open. If the app is not already opened and I say "open {my app} to {book} and {chapter}" it will try to load the app and briefly show the screen before it disappears, presumably from a crash.

I need to debug and figure out what it's trying to do when the app is not already opened. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to debug and figure out what it's trying to do when the app is not already opened. Is there a way to do so?

Of course you could trigger suspend, resume, and background events for Windows Store apps in [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974425.aspx). The following is the brief testing procedure regarding uwp application lifecycle events.

In the Visual Studio debugger, you can manually suspend, resume, and terminate your apps to debug process lifecycle events. To debug a process lifecycle event:

1. Set a breakpooint in the handler of the event that you want to debug.
2. Press F5 to start debugging.
3. On the Debug Location toolbar, choose the event that you want to fire:
   [image]

Note that Suspend and terminate closes the app and ends the debug session.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, there were also some other things that needed to occur on my end. I hadn't properly attached the background task to the project in the package manifest, and also needed to reference it as well.